# How to add ListItem to DropDownList from code and get the selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I succeeded adding List-items to my DropDownList from my database, but after I ran my application and selected a value from the DropDownList, I checked my break point at code and I saw that the selected value is wrong. It always selects the first value.

My code is:

```
UserBLL uBLL = new UserBLL();
List<Item> list = uBLL.GetAllItemsCategory();
foreach (Item item in list)
{
    int var = 1;
    ListItem lItem = new ListItem(item.name, var.ToString());
    modelsList.Add(lItem);
    var++;
}

DropDownList2.DataSource = modelsList;  
DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

How can I fix it so that when the following is executed I'll get the right selection and not just the first item?

```
order.nameItem = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: I assume that you are calling this code on every postback. That's why the selected item is always the first. You are overwriting the selected value with `DropDownList2.DataBind();`. Use `if(!IsPostBack)...` then.

Comment: @Nir.b Where does this code reside? When you post back are you trying to set the DropDownList values again?

Comment: Tim Schmelter, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for `!IsPostBack` in the `Page_Load` event, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Put logic here to bind
        DropDownList2.DataSource = modelsList;  
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
    }
}
```